# Storm Supervisors not starting after machine restart

Tags: clojure, apache-storm

I have been running a storm-0.8.2 cluster for over a year now.  Last night AWS restarted the supervisor machines.  I have tried to restart the supervisor processes manually, but upon start up I receive this error message in the logs.

```
014-10-15 19:48:04 supervisor [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-supervisor

java.net.UnknownHostException: domU-<aws internal ip>: domU-<aws internal ip>

at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1454)

at backtype.storm.util$local_hostname.invoke(util.clj:153)

at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$supervisor_data.invoke(supervisor.clj:181)

at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__4729$exec_fn__1200__auto____4730.invoke(supervisor.clj:331)

at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:167)

at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)

at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:601)

at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__4729$mk_supervisor__4754.doInvoke(supervisor.clj:327)

at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)

at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$_launch.invoke(supervisor.clj:477)

at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$_main.invoke(supervisor.clj:506)

at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)

at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)

at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor.main(Unknown Source)
```

I am not a clojure expert, but it looks like on line 215 of backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor.clj,  that it is possible to set the localhost name in a config file.

```
215 :my-hostname (if (contains? conf STORM-LOCAL-HOSTNAME)
216                (conf STORM-LOCAL-HOSTNAME)
217                 (local-hostname))
```

Is this possible?  What file do I need to set this setting in?  What is the correct key for this setting?

Or am I way off base and need to do something else to get my workers to restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from the user mailing list (user AT storm DOT apache DOT com).  You can set the local host in your conf/storm.yaml file using the key "storm.local.hostname".

Answer (score 1):

I didn't face that situation before but if I were you, I would try:

- Clear the directories used by Storm (the ones your configure in `conf/storm.yaml`.
- If the previous step didn't solve the issue, then try mapping IPs to hostnames in your OS host file.

Comment: I didn't think of mapping IPs to hostnames.  That would have probably worked.  Thanks.  I did find a way to set the local host in the storm.yaml file, which did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Add below entry to storm.yaml file

storm.local.hostname: "localhost"